# question about continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

everyone
can any one solve this problem

> > **Q**) 
> >     show that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> > x\sin(1/x)&\text{if }x\ne0\\
> > 0&\text{if }x=0
> > \end{cases}$$
>
> is continuous on real number?

by using the definition of continuous

I hope someone can solve. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x_0$ one must require
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0-0}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0+0}f(x) = f(x_0)
$$
$x\sin \frac 1x$ is even function, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0-0}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0+0}f(x)$, so you just need to find its value. Let's consider $x\rightarrow 0+0$ limit. $\sin(x)$ is bounded by $-1$ and $1$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0+0}x \sin \frac 1x = 0 = f(0)$

Done.

Comment: thank you Mr Kaster can you please prove by using the definition

Comment: of continuous  this my request thank you very much

Comment: @leenaadam I did use definition. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) one.